# Spritekit | Swift3 | Applying SKWarpGeometry to nodes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3

I've searched the depths of the internet to find some tutorials on implementing SKWarpGeometry on SKSpritenodes to no avail.

I have a Trampoline SKSpritenode and a ball SKSpritenode.

```
 ballNode = childNode(withName: "ballNode") as? SKSpriteNode
    ballNode?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (ballNode?.frame.size.width)! / 2)
    ballNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ballNode?.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    ballNode?.zPosition = 3
    ballNode?.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ballCategory
    ballNode?.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.trampolineCategory
    ballNode?.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.platformCategory
    ballNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
    ballNode?.move(toParent: _gameNode)

enumerateChildNodes(withName: "trampoline") {trampolineNode,_ in
    trampoline = trampolineNode as? SKSpriteNode
    trampolineNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: (trampoline?.size.width)!, height: (trampoline?.size.height)!))
    trampolineNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.trampolineCategory
    trampolineNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ballCategory
    trampolineNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ballCategory
    trampolineNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    trampolineNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    trampolineNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    trampolineNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    trampolineNode.move(toParent: _gameNode)
```

When the ballNode hits the trampoline. I want the top of trampoline node to bend inwards. However by running the following code, the trampoline image disappears.

```
if collision == PhysicsCategory.ballCategory | PhysicsCategory.trampolineCategory {
        let src = [float2(0.0), float2(1.0), float2(2.0),
                   float2(3.0), float2(4.0), float2(5.0),
                   float2(6.0), float2(7.0), float2(8.0)]

        let dst = [float2(0.0), float2(0.0), float2(2.0),
                   float2(3.0), float2(1.0), float2(5.0),
                   float2(6.0), float2(7.0), float2(8.0)]

        warpGrid = SKWarpGeometryGrid(columns: 2, rows: 2,
                                      sourcePositions: src,
                                      destinationPositions: dst)
        //
        trampoline?.warpGeometry = warpGrid     <---This line removes the trampoline image, so I could only assume its the way I set up the source and destination points.

        let transform = SKAction.warp(to: warpGrid!, duration: 1)
        let transformAction = SKAction.repeat(transform!, count: 1)
        trampoline?.run(transformAction)            
    }
```

I could be setting the grid nodes wrong but I have no clue as there are no tutorials to guide me. Has anyone used SKGeometry yet?

Comment: Unfortunately I think the answer to your "has anyone used it yet" question is probably, "no". This was one of those features that nobody (out of the 15 users Sprite Kit has) saw coming. And it's purpose seems limited by its features. There's no easing timings, for example, between the states of warps. It seems to be a half baked idea, with a less than half baked implementation, for the simple purpose of creating swaying grass and trees. When I first listened to their presentation I was excited about doing soft-bodies with it. But after some research, it's certainly not equipped for that.

Comment: Is spritekit not that widely used? wow. Just need a simple example as what I want to do is pretty simple in theory.

Comment: as far as I know, there are zero examples. I looked at using it for a bit, same as you, couldn't find anyone using it. But I also found that I don't think it's intended for my desired usage. What I've found with Apple stuff is that if it's not explicitly designed for something, attempting to meld it to your whims is just frustration and fury. You might be using it as intended. But hard to know, since Apple only ever bothers to make a demo once per year.

Comment: sigh, thanks for your help anyhow.

Comment: Apple have some example code in their `SKWarpGeometry` reference. Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skwarpgeometrygrid

Comment: bloody hell, this is exactly what I needed. I will implement and answer my own question. Thanks.

Comment: @Confused 16, You forgot about me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it. Hope this helps other people!!!

```
//Create your SKSpritenodes
ballNode = childNode(withName: "ballNode") as? SKSpriteNode
ballNode?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: (ballNode?.frame.size.width)! / 2)
ballNode?.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
ballNode?.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
ballNode?.zPosition = 3
ballNode?.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ballCategory
ballNode?.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.trampolineCategory
ballNode?.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.platformCategory
ballNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)
ballNode?.move(toParent: _gameNode)

enumerateChildNodes(withName: "trampoline") {trampolineNode,_ in
trampoline = trampolineNode as? SKSpriteNode
trampolineNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: (trampoline?.size.width)!, height: (trampoline?.size.height)!))
trampolineNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.trampolineCategory
trampolineNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ballCategory
trampolineNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ballCategory
trampolineNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
trampolineNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
trampolineNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
trampolineNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
trampolineNode.move(toParent: _gameNode)

   // Declare the following SKWarpGeometryGrids
   var trampolineWarpGrid: SKWarpGeometryGrid?
   var trampolineNoWarpGrid: SKWarpGeometryGrid?

   // For 2x2 grid - State the source positions
    let sourcePositions: [vector_float2] = [
        vector_float2(0, 0),   vector_float2(0.5, 0),   vector_float2(1, 0),
        vector_float2(0, 0.5), vector_float2(0.5, 0.5), vector_float2(1, 0.5),
        vector_float2(0, 1),   vector_float2(0.5, 1),   vector_float2(1, 1)
    ]

    // For 2x2 grid - State the destination positions
    // To make the dent, I changed row 3 column 2 value from (0.5, 1) to (0.5, 0.8)
    let destinationPositions: [vector_float2] = [
        vector_float2(0, 0),   vector_float2(0.5, 0),   vector_float2(1, 0),
        vector_float2(0, 0.5), vector_float2(0.5, 0.5), vector_float2(1, 0.5),
        vector_float2(0, 1),   vector_float2(0.5, 0.8),   vector_float2(1, 1)
    ]

    //Create the 2x2 warp grid based on the source and destination positions
    trampolineWarpGrid = SKWarpGeometryGrid(columns: 2, rows: 2,
                                  sourcePositions: sourcePositions,
                                  destinationPositions: destinationPositions)

    //Create and assign a Grid to the SKSpritenode that has no warp effects
    //Will be used to convert the trampoline back to original view  
    trampolineNoWarpGrid = SKWarpGeometryGrid(columns: 2, rows: 2)
    trampoline?.warpGeometry = trampolineNoWarpGrid

 func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let collision: UInt32 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    if collision == PhysicsCategory.ballCategory | PhysicsCategory.trampolineCategory {
    //Transform the trampoline grid to show dent
    let transform = SKAction.warp(to: trampolineWarpGrid!, duration: 0.3)
    //Warp the trampoline gird back to normal
    let transformBack = SKAction.warp(to: trampolineNoWarpGrid!, duration: 0.3)
    //Run Action
    let transformAction = SKAction.sequence([transform!, transformBack!])
    trampoline?.run(SKAction.repeat(transformAction, count: 1))
}
```